# Need some advice on creating cloud storage for users of my app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, cloud, storage

What server side technologies would i need to learn to develop a cloud based storage system for users using my service?

Currently i am using java spring and hibernate and have developed a login system. I am wondering how would i be able to store users's files on my server separately for each user and allow access to files accordingly.

Comment: One option would be to just use an already available cloud storage system like S3 from AWS of maybe Dropbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for a document-oriented database: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database

In case you're not allowed to use a fully managed service such as S3, there are options like MongoDB cluster: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/architecture.html

"The following AWS components are deployed and configured as part of this reference deployment:

- A VPC configured with public and private subnets across three Availability Zones.*
- In the public subnets, NAT gateways to allow outbound internet connectivity for resources (MongoDB instances) in the private subnets. (For more information, see the Amazon VPC Quick Start.)*
- In the public subnets, bastion hosts in an Auto Scaling group with Elastic IP addresses to allow inbound Secure Shell (SSH) access. One bastion host is deployed by default, but this number is configurable. (For more information, see the Linux bastion host Quick Start.)*
- An AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) instance role with fine-grained permissions for access to AWS services necessary for the deployment process.
- Security groups to enable communication within the VPC and to restrict access to only necessary protocols and ports.
- In the private subnets, a customizable MongoDB cluster with the option of running standalone or in replica sets, along with customizable Amazon EBS storage. The Quick Start launches each member of the replica set in a different Availability Zone. However, if you choose an AWS Region that doesn’t provide three or more Availability Zones, the Quick Start reuses one of the zones to create the third subnet.
- You can choose to launch the Quick Start for a new VPC or use your existing VPC. The template that deploys the Quick Start into an existing VPC skips the creation of components marked by asterisks and prompts you for your existing configuration."